# How to send an array from a drop down selection form to another page with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a drop down input form. I want the selection to be put into an array, and then sent to another page to be displayed. But for some reason, it is not printing.

Let me show you my code so that you can get a better understanding.

Here's what my drop down input form looks like

```
<label>Start Month:</label>
    <select>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Jan">Jan</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Feb">Feb</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="March">March</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="April">April</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="May">May</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="June">June</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="July">July</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Aug">Aug</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Sept">Sept</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Oct">Oct</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Nov">Nov</option>
         <option name="sMonth[]" value="Dec">Dec</option>
    </select>
```

On the NEXT php page:

```
<?php $sMonth=$_POST['sMonth']; // start month  ?>

<?php echo $sMonth[0]; ?>
```

But it doesn't print anything.

NOTE = I'm aware that from the drop down menu, the selection will be put into the 1st elemental position of the array. I want to print the first element. If I can print the first element, I will be able to print the rest of the elements.

Comment: Is your form set to `action="post"`? Why pass value as array here?

Comment: No, its action=second.php and method="post

Comment: Sorry meant `method="post"` :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the SELECT, this should contain the name

```
<select name="sMonth[]" multiple>
    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
```

etc.

Comment: what is the multiple for? I don't want ALL of the options to be set into it. I just want the month selected by the user to be set into the array.

Comment: Then you can leave multiple away, you normally use an array for multiple values, this is the way with an SELECT

Comment: Arrays are typically used when you want multiple values in a single variable. Since you want to use an array, people are assuming you want a multiple select element. If not, then it might make more sense not to use an array in your HTML, and to convert it to an array on the server side with `$months = array ($_POST['sMonth']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Here you made mistake of HTML.

In dd control, SELECT statement contains name property && OPTION statement contains value property. So just change this and your code will working properly.

i.e.

<select name="sMonth[]">

&&

remove name from option tag.
```

- Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<label>Start Month:</label>
    <select name="sMonth">
         <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
         <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
         <option value="March">March</option>
         <option value="April">April</option>
         <option value="May">May</option>
         <option value="June">June</option>
         <option value="July">July</option>
         <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
         <option value="Sept">Sept</option>
         <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
         <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
         <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
    </select>

<?php $months = $_POST['sMonth']; // start month  ?>

<?php print_r($months) ?>
```

Comment: what is the multiple for? I don't want ALL of the options to be set into it. I just want the month selected by the user to be set into the array.

Answer (score -2):

The way you create select dropdown is wrong.
WHY?
Because name tag is not placed in the option tag.
Option tag is only suppossed to carry the value.
Plece your name tag into the selectr tag and you will see your variable is passed into the php.
try this:

```
 <label>Start Month:</label>
        <select name="sMonth">
             <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
             <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
             <option value="March">March</option>
             <option value="April">April</option>
             <option value="May">May</option>
             <option value="June">June</option>
             <option value="July">July</option>
             <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
             <option value="Sept">Sept</option>
             <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
             <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
             <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
        </select>
    //in your php capture your month as below
    <?php $sMonth=$_POST['sMonth']; // start month  ?>

var_dump($_POST['sMonth']);
//you will see your selected value.
```